# UITabBarController - values do not refresh in 2nd execution. Retains the calculated values from Run 1

Tags: ios4, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, refresh

2nd Tab  when input new values doesnt refresh. The application has to be restarted in the simulator for the new values to take effect.

How the app is setup:

In Tab 1, there are text fields take in values. I have a Submit button which passes the values to AppDelegate which is then reused in Tab 2. 
First Run : Input the values on Tab 1 and press Tab 2 - All labels are refreshed properly with correct calculated values.

Second Run : Input a different set of values on Tab 1 and press Tab 2. The values on labels still retain the calculated values from Run 1.

Then I restart the app on simulator and input the values on Tab 1 and I get the results as expected. But when I start a new execution the values are retained from the first run.

I am a newbie with 1 week into iPhone development. So please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are updating your labels on viewDidLoad of "tab 2", when you probably want to do that in viewWillAppear: instead.

Hard to say for sure without seeing some code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. You may be right - my calculations are in viewDidLoad() method. 
There is no viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear method defined in my .m file. Will implement this tonite and reply with the observations.

Quick Q: If I move my code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear wouldn't the labels be empty the first time the view is loaded? I might be wrong!!

Comment: The first time this viewController is shown, you'll see viewDidLoad and then viewWillAppear:. So you'll be fine from that perspective. But when you go back to tab 1, tab 2's view won't necessarily be unloaded, so that's why you're not getting viewDidLoad each time you return to tab 2.

Comment: Just logged back into StackOverflow and saw ur 2nd comment. Thanks for that. I got that resolved with your inputs. Cheers.